# stop WCF from caching / re-using security tokens (SecurityContextToken)

Tags: wcf, wcf-security, ws-security

I am using WCF Message level security with the following wsHttpBinding

```
  <security mode="Message">
    <message clientCredentialType="Windows" establishSecurityContext="false" />
  </security>
```

- Each time i call the service is a separate operation, and there is no need to keep any session state.
- I am running into a problem with load balancer, because WCF keeps re-using security tokens, so if the first call goes to NodeA, it creates a security token which is re-used. If that token is passed to NodeB tripping up ***MessageSecurityException***
- Seems like microsofts answer to this is to use sticky sessions, which is something we explored but it does not make sense in our setup

Is there a way to simply force WCF to create a new Security Token on every call? (while using Message level security with Windows credential type?

**update**

i setup trace on client / server and i can i see that the token is cached for 24 hrs.

```
<ServiceToken>
<SessionTokenType>System.ServiceModel.Security.Tokens.BufferedGenericXmlSecurityToken</SessionTokenType>
<ValidFrom>2013-03-23T21:21:32.569Z</ValidFrom>
<ValidTo>2013-03-24T07:21:32.569Z</ValidTo>
<InternalTokenReference>LocalIdKeyIdentifierClause(LocalId = 'uuid-291b4a38-af17-4832-bc7a-6fb65dcc3c3c-18', Owner = 'System.ServiceModel.Security.Tokens.SecurityContextSecurityToken')</InternalTokenReference>
```

> The IssuanceTokenProvider used the cached service token.

i've tried disabling token cashing using the following:

```
IssuedTokenClientCredential itcc = service.ClientCredentials.IssuedToken;
itcc.CacheIssuedTokens = false;
itcc.LocalIssuerAddress = new EndpointAddress("http://localhost:####/myservice");
itcc.LocalIssuerBinding = new WSHttpBinding("my_wsHttp_bindingConfig");
itcc.MaxIssuedTokenCachingTime = new TimeSpan(0,0,0);
```

but looking at the wcf trace, it appears that above doesn't affect the negotiation at all.

i am still seeing that cached tokens are used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

after a lot of research, and pouring through the WCF trace, and contacting Microsoft, i got to the bottom of this problem.

1. when using message level security, WCF issues **Security Context Token** based authentication (SCT)
2. this type of authentication simply relies on sticky session, no way around it.
3. there is a setting which is supposed to disable it EstablishSecurityContext=false, but this does not work. after setting this i can see in a trace that SCT's are being used just as before (and i got someone at Microsoft to confirm i wasn't doing anything unusual here). There might be another dependency on this setting, but a senior MS engineer didn't know why this setting wasn't working either.
4. this leaves a few options

   a. use "one shot" calls with Kerberos - i did not explore this because turning on kerberos in my scenario would have been a bigger headache

   b. use a custom binding with NTLM based auth - i tried this, but SCT's were still being used, so it didn't work for me

   c. use federated security with custom Token issuing service. This gives a finer control over how tokens are issued, but with unnecessary (in my case) overhead of having to manage this

   **d. use basic http binding with TransportCredentialOnly security mode.** this is nice because it stops SCT negotiation, while still passing a windows credential.

4.d was the easiest for me because i didn't have to do a lot of changes besides config. i am giving up wshttpbinding features, but so far this is ok because this conversation is happening within a trusted network.